# MongoDB - performance and collection size

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

I have a question with regards to collection sizes and query performance –

There are 2 dbs– DB1 & DB2. DB1 has 1 collection, and here’s the output from stats() on this collection –

```
{
    …
   "count" : 2085217,
    "size" : 17048734192,
    "avgObjSize" : 8176,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "indexDetails" : {},
    "totalIndexSize" : 606299456,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 67664576,
        "id_1" : 284165056,
        "id_2" : 254469824
    },
…
}
```

A query on this collection, using index id_1 comes back in 0.012 secs. Here’s the output from explain() -

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1, 
       ….
                "indexName" : "id_1",
            }
```

In DB2, I have 4 collections, and here’s the output from stats on DB2 –

```
{
    …
    "collections" : 4,
    "objects" : 152655935,
    "avgObjSize" : 8175.998307514215,
    "dataSize" : 1248114666192,
    "storageSize" : 1257144933456,
    "indexes" : 12,
    "indexSize" : 19757688272,
    "fileSize" : 1283502112768,
…
}
```

A query on any collection in DB2, using the index, which I confirmed via explain(), takes at least double the time that it does for the previous query against DB1.

Since mongo should scale well, why is there this diff? I read that mongodb loads all the indexes in memory, and since DB2 has a higher volume than DB1, is that why it’s taking much longer?

Any insights would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Edit 1:
Adding more info re. collection definition, indexes definitions and queries executed...

All collections (in both DBs) contain the same fields; only the values and the size of documents differ between them.

And, here's the relevant index -

```
"1" : {
     "v" : 1,
     "unique" : true,
     "key" : {
        "id" : 1
     },
     "name" : "id_1",
     "ns" : "ns.coll1"
   }
```

And, this is how the id field looks like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55f9b6548aefbce6b2fa2fac"),
"id" : {
   "pid" : {
    "f1" : "val1",
    "f2" : "val2"
   }
},
```

And, here's a sample query -

```
db.coll1.find({id:{pid:{f1:"val1",f2:"val2"}}})
```

Edit 2:
Here's some more info on the hard disk & RAM -

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         386758        3750        1947       25283      381060      355675
Swap:        131071        3194      127877
```

The hard disk is around 3.5T, out of which 2.9T is already used.

Comment: Can you give more details? Collection definition, indexes definitions and queries executed?

Comment: I edited my original post above to add more information. Thanks.

Comment: If there is not enough RAM for hot data, queries will be slow since disk will need to be accessed.

Comment: I updated my post t include memory info. What exactly is the hot data? Is it the entire collection that a query goes against, or is just the indexes? If it's the latter, should I ensure that the free space in RAM be large enough to support the indexSize of a collection? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Scaling

MongoDB scales very well. The thing is, it is designed to scale horizontally, not vertically. This means that if your DBs are holding a lot of data, you should shard the collections in order to achieve better parallelization.

#### Benchmark results

Regarding the difference in query time, I don't think your profiling is conclusive. The DBs are possibly on different machines (with different specs). Supposing the hardware is the same, DB2 apparently holds more documents on its collections and the size of documents are not the same on both DBs. The same query can return data sets with different sizes. That will inevitably have impact on data serialization and other low level aspects. Unless you profile the queries in a more controlled setup, I think your results are pretty much expected.

#### Suggestions

- Take care if you are using DRef on your documents. Its possible Mongo will automatically dereference them; that means more that data to serialize and overhead.
- Try running the same queries with a `limit` specification. You have defined the index to be unique, but I don't know if that automatically makes Mongo stop index traversal once it has found a value. Check if `db.coll1.find({id:{pid:{f1:"val1",f2:"val2"}}})` and `db.coll1.find({id:{pid:{f1:"val1",f2:"val2"}}}).limit(1)` run on the same time.
- Take a look at [Indexes on embedded fields](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-embedded-fields) and [Indexes on embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-embedded-documents). Embedded documents seem to impair even extra overhead.

Finally, if your document has no embedded documents, only embedded fields (which seems to be the case), then define your index more specifically. Create this index

```
db.coll1.createIndex({"id.pid.f1": 1, "id.pid.f2": 1}, {unique: true})
```

and run the query again. If this index doesn't improve performance, then I believe you have done everything properly and it may be time to start [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Both my DBs are in the same machine, so we can eliminate hardware being different. Each query (against both the DB) should return only 1 document, since I'm basically supplying only the index fields (which are unique) as the query parameter.

Comment: The index is unique as your definition shows. But the doc only tells us that Mongo uses that in order to impose data consistency. It fails if you try to insert non-unique values. But the doc does not mention if uniqueness is used to optimize queries. It is possible that Mongo finds your document and still keeps going with the query to find other documents. I don't think this is the case; I believe Mongo is well implemented. But you should still try using `limit(1)` to ensure that Mongo is smart enough when in doubt.

Comment: Sorry, my previous response was cut off.
Re. the other suggestions - there's no DRef in the documents; running with or without limit(1) takes similar time for retrieval; and there's no embedded documents in the data set. Also, I do have the index you mentioned, and I use a query like below so that it uses this index, but the performance is the same.
db.coll1.find({"id:.pid.f1":"val1","id:.pid.f2":"val2"}}})

Comment: Then you have done nothing wrong it seems. Maybe the problem is indeed the large index trashing your RAM.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like sharding's the way to go.

Comment: Actually there are some other strategies you could try. I don't think they will improve much your performance, but they are worth giving a shot. Do you want me to update my answer to include them?

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could update your answer with the new suggestions. Thanks much.

Comment: Ok, I'll run some tests on my work station and edit the answer after. The tests will also be useful since I have an SSD here so we can check if you query is slow because of HD.